# Why does the WinForms designer generate somewhat 'inconvenient' code in its dispose method?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

When you create a form or a user control, the WinForms designer generates a dispose method that looks like this:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it can lead to incorrect behaviour if it is ever edited to dispose of additional objects. I have seen .designer.cs files with dispose methods that look like this:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
            if (_myDisposable != null)
                _myDisposable.Dispose();
            if (_myOtherDisposable != null)
                _myOtherDisposable.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

... which is incorrect, as the disposal of _myDisposable and _myOtherDisposable should not depend on whether or not components is null.

So, ignoring the argument about whether or not it is good practice to edit this designer generated code, and ignoring the fact that you can change it by editing the templates, my question is: Why doesn't the designer generate code that looks more like this?

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if(components != null)
                components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

This code has the same end result, but is safer and less prone to errors during modification.

Comment: The first and third code blocks are (nearly) the same. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Erno - You are right, since `&&` will short circuit.

Comment: So there is no question (spoon)?

Comment: The if statement in the first code block will only be entered if disposing is true AND components is not null, which means that any additional stuff you put inside it will not be executed if components is null. The if statement in the third block will be entered whenever disposing is true, so that is is safe to put additional stuff inside it.

Comment: As-is, the blocks are equivalent. But if you want to dispose of additional stuff by putting it inside the if() statement, their behavior will be different.

Comment: It isn't generated code, it came from the item template.  You can edit it anyway you want, it is best to cut/paste it into your regular form.cs file.  You only need to stay away from the #region.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: because your convenience was not the primary concern of whoever wrote this function at Microsoft. Or perhaps they thought that you, being a non-Microsoft employee, cannot possibly be any good as a programmer, therefore, you should probably stay away from risky businesses such as modifying an object's Dispose() method.

By the way, the Dispose() method lies outside of the area within the .Designer.cs file which is designated as "do not edit this designer generated code", so I suppose it is okay to edit it.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that this is because the Microsoft's "official" `IDisposable` pattern tries to accomodate too many situations, unnecessarily.

For more details, see this excellent article by Stephen Cleary: **[What your mother never told you about IDisposable]https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About)**. He has some great insights into the issues with `IDisposable`, and how to fix them.

Stephen offers one simple guideline: just don't mix managed and unmanaged resources in a single class; instead, wrap every unmanaged resource in an `IDisposable` class whose sole purpose is to dispose of the unmanaged resource.

If one follows this guideline, such arcane `Dispose` methods stop being necessary, at the same time as solving a whole bunch of other, more serious issues with Microsoft's recommended pattern.

Comment: +1.  Even so, after wrapping them in IDisposable it is still necessary to invoke `Dispose()` when you're done with them, either explicitly or via `using ( ) { }`.  Otherwise the behaviour isn't much better than having not wrapped them at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're right mostly, and you didn't even mention the fact that it is placed inside the Designer.cs file.

You'll have to first move it (to MyForm.cs) and then edit it. With some common sense...

But it is largely academic, <strike>components==null will only be true on a completely empty Form. Drop 1 Button or Label and the issue doesn't come up.</strike>

I just checked, even on an empty Form it is not `null`. (OK, just for Fx 4+ apparently)

Comment: Components never seems to be null in VS 2010, but in VS 2008 and below it will always be null unless you specifically add a component such as a Timer to your form.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to handle Disposal of contained resources on a Form is to use the FormClosing or FormClosed events.  UserControl has a Disposed event for the same purpose.

Comment: Closing and Closed are both obsolete, replaced by FormClosing and FormClosed in .NET 2.0.  Where did you find that recommendation?

Comment: @Hans, I've edited the response accordingly; I was told verbally a few years back to use Closing/Closed and I forgot that they were actually named FormClosing and FormClosed.  I wasn't actually aware there were obsolete events with the other names.